# Pandas dataframe modified by NumPy function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Say I have a dataframe called "table" with two columns named "a" and "b":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.random as rd
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = rd.normal(0,1,(2,5))
>>> table = pd.DataFrame({'a':x[0], 'b':x[1]})

>>> table[['a','b']]
       a         b
0  0.284503  1.278977
1 -1.088041  0.688201
2  1.205980  0.182008
3 -0.083491 -0.688141
4  0.282274  1.854735
```

Now, when I correctly compute sin-inverse I get following as expected.

```
>>> np.arcsin( table.a/table.b)

0    0.224322
1         NaN
2         NaN
3    0.121628
4    0.152785
dtype: float64
```

But when I do this mistakenly (note above was `arcsin(y/x)` whereas below I do `arcsin(y, x)` ),

```
>>> np.arcsin( table.a.values,table.b.values)
array([ 0.28848814,         nan,         nan, -0.08358827,  0.28616372])
```

What gave me a heart attack is that the incorrect NumPy operation has modified `table` even though I am using `.values` above.

```
>>> table[['a','b']]
        a         b
0  0.284503  0.288488
1 -1.088041       NaN
2  1.205980       NaN
3 -0.083491 -0.083588
4  0.282274  0.286164
```

You see that column b is modified.

Is this expected behaviour? Why should NumPy modify the dataframe? Any academic insight would be much appreciated.

I guess the question why I would attempt to call function wrong way in the first place is not very important here. My concern is not to repeat similar mistake for some other function in the future unknowingly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Operations on a pandas.DataFrame should always return a new object.

Comment: Could you create a **minimal** complete example, which shows this behaviour?

Comment: I still cannot reproduce this. What are your os, python version, numpy version, pandas version

Comment: Os: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Python: 2.7.10
Numpy: 1.9.2
Pandas: 0.16.2
Repo: Anaconda 2.2.0
Ipython: 3.0.0 . Enter vs Shift Enter is the culprit for multiple edits. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional second argument to [`numpy.arcsin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arcsin.html) is an output array. If you give the function two arguments, it takes the arcsine of the values in the first argument and writes them into the second argument.

This mode is provided to increase efficiency when you have a large array sitting around and want to reuse the memory without deallocating and reallocating it.

So, yes, this is expected behavior. Be careful not to provide two arguments if you don't want the second one to be overwritten. You may have been thinking of the [`numpy.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2) function, which *does* take two input arguments (and an optional third argument for the output array). But that is the only one of the trigonometric functions that takes two input arguments.

Comment: IMHO this would have been a good time to use a keyword-only argument, so that you'd have to specify `out=` if you wanted it.  But the ship may have sailed on changing the API by now..

Comment: Just to make this complete, I like to add that when .values is not used and I try to execute [`numpy.arcsin( table.a, table.b )`] it throws [`TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType`], which is understandable. But the ability to modify the original dataframe even when not fed directly is something for me to be careful about.

Comment: Totally missed that the second call had a `, ` instead of  a `/`

Comment: @MaxNoe no worries! every mistake teaches something. I learnt about **minimal complete example**.